# Not including stl libraries in C++ project during building in cross platform project Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I'm trying to build a shared library. However I don't have a single clue of why I'm getting the following error:

```
2>  ANT_HOME=D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
2>  JAVA_HOME=
2>  NDK_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b
2>  ProjectDLL.cpp
2>  In file included from ..\ProjectDLL\ProjectDLL.cpp:1:
2>  In file included from ..\ProjectDLL/ProjectDLL.h:4:
2>  In file included from C:\Users\User\ProjectMaterialCapture\ProjectVSSolution\Project\../ProjectSourceCode/headers\Project.hh:10:
2>  In file included from C:\Users\User\ProjectMaterialCapture\ProjectVSSolution\Project\../ProjectSourceCode/headers\capture.hh:11:
2>  In file included from C:\Users\User\ProjectMaterialCapture\ProjectVSSolution\Project\../ProjectSourceCode/headers\myCommons.hh:11:
2>  In file included from C:\Users\User\ProjectMaterialCapture\ProjectVSSolution\Project\../../dependencies/opencv-sdk-3.4.1/sdk/native/jni/include\opencv2/core/core.hpp:48:
2>  In file included from C:\Users\User\ProjectMaterialCapture\ProjectVSSolution\Project\../../dependencies/opencv-sdk-3.4.1/sdk/native/jni/include\opencv2/core.hpp:52:
2>  In file included from C:\Users\User\ProjectMaterialCapture\ProjectVSSolution\Project\../../dependencies/opencv-sdk-3.4.1/sdk/native/jni/include\opencv2/core/cvdef.h:91:
2>C:\Users\User\ProjectMaterialCapture\ProjectVSSolution\Project\../../dependencies/opencv-sdk-3.4.1/sdk/native/jni/include\opencv2/core/hal/interface.h(15,10): fatal error : 'cstddef' file not found
2>  #include <cstddef>
2>           ^
2>  1 error generated.
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've tried to check If that header is actually in my ndk folder, and it is there. Can you give me any clue on why I'm getting such error?

Thx

**Update**: Am I supposed to do:

> LLVM's libc++ is the C++ standard library that has been used by the
>   Android OS since Lollipop, and in the future will be the only STL
>   available in the NDK.
>
> Until NDK r16, the NDK's libc++ is only of beta quality. Beginning
>   with NDK r16, libc++ will be the preferred STL. A future NDK release
>   will remove the other options.
>
> The shared library for this runtime is libc++_shared.so, and the
>   static library is libc++_static.a.
>
> libc++ is dual-licensed under both the University of Illinois
>   "BSD-Like" license and the MIT license. For more information, see the
>   license file.

? But isn't this handled by the following

[image]

?

**Update**:

Apparently the problem is more related to the combination "Android"+"ARM". I've just created a shared library from scratch, if I set the target to be `Debug/Release ARM` I get all this error:

```
1>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin\ld : error : cannot find -lgnustl_static
```

Still I don't know why.

Comment: Have you set which STL to use in the project? see: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html  As Android NDK supports more than one STL, it defaults to none.

Comment: How do I set that?

Comment: Read the link it tells you.

Comment: I read the link, but still not sure I've understood. Should I change some CMake file somehow?

Comment: See my update, is that what you meant?